# How to set display value of operators of FilterBuilder?

Tags: smartgwt

I am using filter builder.
I have set Filter builder's top operator as BRACKET.
I am trying to change the default display value of operators but somehow its not working.
Check the code below.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
    final FilterBuilder filterBuilder = new FilterBuilder();
                    filterBuilder.setDataSource(FilterDS.getInstance(member));
                    filterBuilder.setValidateOnChange(true);
                    filterBuilder.setAlign(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
                    filterBuilder.setTopOperatorAppearance(TopOperatorAppearance.BRACKET);
                    filterBuilder.setMatchAllTitle("AND");
                    filterBuilder.setMatchAnyTitle("OR");
                    filterBuilder.setMatchNoneTitle("NOT");
```